# Select Queries From Parent-Child Tables Model

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables (parent-child model): Loans & Transactions.

Each Loan row has multiple Transaction rows.

I want to select all rows from Loans together with most recent row from Transactions.

Here is my select to achieve this.

```
SELECT 
    L.*, T.*
FROM Loans L
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Transactions AS T
    WHERE L.LoanID = T.LoanID
    ORDER BY CRTime DESC
) T
```

Another approach

```
SELECT 
    L.*, T.*
FROM Loans L
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(TransactionID) AS TransactionID, LoanID FROM Transactions AS T
    GROUP BY LoanID
) T
ON T.LoanID = L.LoanID
INNER JOIN Transactions TS
ON TS.TransactionID = T.TransactionID
```

Any ideas on improving it?

Side question: Can you suggest best practices for comparing two queries running times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Select *

Generally, it is advised against using `SELECT *`. The answers to this stackoverflow question explain [why `SELECT *` is considered harmful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

## Your queries might return different values

The first query takes the transaction record with the latest `CRTime`, the second uses the highest ID. These are likely returning the same rows right now, but I would use the `CRTime`. The rows might not have been inserted in time order, so the most recent time and the highest ID might not result in the same record.

## I would recommend the first query

I would recommend the first query because it avoids that second join that the second query has. Other than changing the `SELECT *`s to list all the columns and making sure the tables are properly indexed, I don't think there is much you can do to improve it. That's a pretty nice query.

## Select * and Indexing

One of the problems pointed out in the linked SO question is that fact that using `SELECT *` can cause the query to not use indexing properly as it brings back more columns than you need.

## Checking runtimes

I found this stackoverflow question had some good answers regarding [comparing SQL runtimes/performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764011/how-to-compare-two-queries)

Comment: @PenutReeaper Thanks for response. `T.*` and `L.*` war just for the purpose of making the query shorter for codereview site. Anyways, it's gonna help others!